# Connecting to CIFS shares from a VPN where the ports 137,138,139 and 445 are closed

Tags: c#, vpn, cifs

I'm trying for a few days to connect to cifs files from an azure (well DXC from episerver) to a some files shared through VPN. The problem is that the ports 137,138,139 and 445 are closed and we have no way of opening them. 
I can connect to that VPN from my machine and can download the files using something like

```
var text = File.ReadAllText(@"\\192.168.1.66\Exports\DXC\Products.xml");
```

I use impersonation since I need to pass credentials (advapi32.dll LogonUser method)
But it looks to use the exact same ports that are blocked on the cloud.

Is there some way of redirecting the traffic to another port. For example we have the 135 port open and could probably open more, but not the ports that are actually used.

Thank you

Comment: if your vpn allows you to download the file then those ports are open on the vpn - set routing to get to that server via the vpn

Comment: They are open on the VPN if I am on that VPN. But not on Azure VPN(DXC).
Can I route the trafic that happens on port 139 to happen on port 135.

Comment: often vpns take over routing and its point to point.. so all traffic now goes to the vpn. this sounds more like a networking question than code issue

Comment: And if so do I need to change the File.ReadAllText method or provide it some parameters?